# Подсветка синтаксиса vs Code

Tags: синтаксис, visual-studio-code, цвета

Как в vs Code настроить необходимую мне подсветку синтаксиса html, css, js?
Как в sublime например я сам выбираю какой елемент, тег или класс каким цветом светиться??

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего Visual Studio Code не распознал расширение файла. Нужно ассоциировать этот файл с каким-нибудь синтаксисом.

Самый быстрый способ:

1. Открываем нужный файл
2. Жмем [Ctrl + K], затем [M] — раскрывается меню выбора синтаксиса
3. Выбираем нужный язык из dropdown-списка / или отправляемся в магазин Visual Studio Code за нужным расширением.